# Exoskeleton Bug Identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found these bug shells / exoskeletons / casings in the corner of my room and I am wondering what they could be. They are about 1-2 cm long. The light colored spots on the floor are likely related. I was thinking they might be from pill bugs, but this is a second-floor room so I am unsure. Located in NW Washington, USA. [image]

Thank you!

Comment: They are all wrapped in spider web, so you have a nice spider keeping your bugs down. If you could unwrap a few, then you might be able to get an ID. I suspect several different types of insects. The bottom middle (darker one) is likely a cranefly or something similarly leggy.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Looks to me like a spider has been feeding on a mixture of things including something pill bug like — I suspect the spots are spider droppings. Can you try opening up some of the little sacks and getting clearer pictures of the contents? Also, you might want to  check above where you found the bodies for webbing or a spider.